# Does the `is` operator in a `when` expression have to see a "hardcoded" type?

Tags: kotlin

Example code:

```
class IsTesting(val myProperty: Int) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean = when(other) {
        is IsTesting -> this.myProperty == other.myProperty
        else -> false
    }
}

fun main() {
    val a = IsTesting(42)
    val b = IsTesting(42)
    if (a == b)
        println("equal")
    else
        println("not equal")
}
```

I'm not a fan of hardcoding the class name there, but kotlin won't let me do

```
        is this::class -> this.myProperty == other.myProperty
```

I see this error:

```
Error:(3, 12) Kotlin: Type expected
```

Is there a workaround, or am I stuck?

Comment: "when" and "is" are not very helpful words to add to a search query :(

Comment: [data-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `is this::class` because you are comparing it to `other`, which is an `Any?`. This would not be a useful comparison anyway, because `this::class` is a `KClass<IsTesting>`, not an `IsTesting`.

You would want to compare `other::class` to `this::class` with an equality check, not an `is` check. But first you have to check if `other` is null, or you can't get its class. But also, smart casting can't infer from the `::class` comparisons the type of `other`, so you also have to check that.

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
    other ?: return false
    if (other !is IsTesting)
        return false
    return when(other::class) {
        this::class -> this.myProperty == other.myProperty
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Your example code is only OK for a final class. For an open class, it would match subclasses that might have extra properties.

Also consider `data class`, which doesn't require you to write an `equals` function.

I don't think there's any way to avoid hard-coding the class name somewhere in here because `other` comes as an Any and you have to cast it to `IsTesting` to be able to access its property.